# Adding Spring config file to application context

Tags: java, spring

There's a Spring config file looking like this:

```
<beans>
    <import resource="/asdasd.xml" />
    <import resource="/asdasdr/asdadxml" />
    <import resource="/asdasd/asdad.xml" />
</beans>
```

All those files are on the classpath and inside the project. They are referenced through the relative path to the Spring config file.

Now I want to add to this config file some other Spring config file, not in this project, but in a dependency and as well on the classpath.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<import  resource="classpath:com/company/common/otherconfig.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<import resource="classpath:/path/to/spring-file.xml"/>
```